# Specialize template from class to integer

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I am playing with template specializations to learn their limits, and I was trying now not to specialize based on *type*, but using an *integer parameter*. But I am failing.

For instance, a template `template <class T>` should be specialized to have `T` for instance a string, but having an additional template parameter as `template <int I>`.

What does the standard say, and how can I do (if it can be done)? My code follows.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <class T, class... U>
class many
{
public:

  T t;

  std::tuple<U...> u;
};


template <int size>
class many<int>
{
    // ???
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  many<int, std::string, char> m;

  m.t = -1;

  std::get<0>(m.u) = "hello";
  std::get<1>(m.u) = 'w';

  std::cout << "many: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << m.t << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::get<0>(m.u) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::get<1>(m.u) << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: To specialize get rid of the template parameter definition: `template <int size>` => `template <>`

Comment: Ok, but what if I want a compile-time integer parameter? I'd really like to have it as `template <int size>`...

Comment: You cannot, this would require to specialize for something like `template <>
class many<5>` or such, but integral types must be given as template parameters explicitly AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to specialize it for different integer values, it uses an extra type that you have to specialize further.
It is pretty straightforward:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

#include <string>

template <class T, class... U>
struct many
{
  T t;
  std::tuple<U...> u;
};

template<int N>
using Int = std::integral_constant<int, N>;

typedef Int <1> One;
typedef Int <2> Two;

template <>
struct many<int>
{ };

template <>
class many<One>
{ };

template <>
class many<Two>
{ };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  many<int, std::string, char> m;
  many<One, char> m2;
  m.t = -1;
  std::get<0>(m.u) = "hello";
  std::get<1>(m.u) = 'w';

  std::cout << "many: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << m.t << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::get<0>(m.u) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::get<1>(m.u) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach I can think of, too. Though it's better to use what the STL provides: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant

Comment: nice, I didn't know about `integral_constant`, it would be indeed allow to reuse the stl to do basically what I've coded. Traits are paramount in the stl, it sort of makes sense that there was something there already. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielJour I upgraded the answer to use `integral_constant`